# node.js second spawned child process doesn't receive stdin messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipc, child-process, spawn

I have an event in my node.js script which need to be called multiple times that spawns a child process. Not parallel just one child process at the time.

```
    var child = spawn('node', [script, arg1],{cwd: "./", stdio:  ["pipe","pipe","pipe","ipc"]})
```

I need to send messages to that child process. With the first spawned process it works just fine with:

```
      child.stdin.write("my_message")//also tried child.stdin.write("my_message\n")
```

The listener on the spawned script looks like that:

```
process.stdin.on("data", async(data)=> {
    //dosomething
    process.exit();
 }
```

But when the first child process is done and closed and the second child process is spawned the `child.stdin.write("my_message")` doesn't reach the child process.

I thought there is a problem with the stdtin channel not closing when the child process exited.
So I tried `process.stdin.end();` on the child process and all the following functions on the `child.on("close")` and `child.on("exit")` events

```
child.on("close", (data)=>{

console.log("Child process closed")
//child.stdin.end();
//child.stdout.end();
//child.stdin.destroy();
//child.kill("SIGINT");
//child = undefined;
//child.disconnect();
//child.ref(); })
```

I also tried sending messages trough ipc. But this throws 'ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED' when trying to send a message to the second spawned child.

node --version
v14.17.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outsourcing the function that spawns the child processes and the associated listeners in an external module actually worked. Not sure why.

```
//spawnChild.js
module.exports = function(arg1){

   var child = spawn('node', [script, arg1],{cwd: "./", stdio:  ["pipe","pipe","pipe","ipc"]})

   //plus the unmodified child.stderr, child.stdout... listeners in here
}
```

Calling the new module in the main script with:

```
var childProcess = require("./spawnChild.js")(arg1)
```

Comment: Also noticed that writing on the stdin of the second spawned child process on node version **v10.19.0** is still not working with this approach. Node version v14.17.5 is working.